# My HTML file is linking another css that I didn't even imported or linked

Tags: html, css, angular, visual-studio-code

I am working on a project where I have created some forms including dropdowns. I have used bootstrap components for dropdowns. I also have other pages in my project. They are working fine individually. Now the problem that I am facing is when I reload my Client-Requirement page all components are aligned as I needed but when I click and visit Admin page and then come back to my Client-Requirement page it becomes miss-aligned. I have different CSS file for my Client-Requirement page and Admin page respectively. After clicking on Admin page if I go back to Client-Requirement page it applies the CSS of Admin page to Client-Requirement page. It feels sort of overlapping of CSS. I need a solution for that.
[This is before visiting admin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFky4.png)  [This is after visiting admin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O3UF.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/css/util.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>  
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="inputState">Lead-Type</label>
        <select id="status1" class="form-control">
          <option selected>Lead-Status</option>
          <option>Demand</option>
          <option>Supply</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
          <label for="inputState">Sub-Type</label>
          <select id="status1" class="form-control">
            <option selected>Lead-Status</option>
            <option>Looking Tenant</option>
            <option>Sell</option>
            <option>Buy</option>
            <option>Looking for Rent</option>
          </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to debug it.  But still I am not getting why this CSS is getting overlapped by another CSS

Comment: Can you please share any stackblitz demo

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Can you please add some codes where you think bug is raised or can you reproduced it here somehow, it'll be easy to debug and give a solution for you matter, if you can upload your code base to git or something and share the link here

Comment: Can you share your code? Sounds like you have two CSS classes, that overlap each other.

Comment: maybe you have done all the styling in `style.css` and also in your component css

Comment: @Tomse yes maybe but what will be solution for it?

Comment: @LovepreetGill Give specific `id` to both client and admin page HTML files and use that id as the parent selector and then write CSS classes based on that. This can be one of the solution or provide stackblitz demo to identify the root cause.